# scrapy data in the same item from multiple link in the same page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

How do I parse with scrapy data to same item from multiple links in the same page? I'm not trying to save data of just a link of a subpage, but something equivalente to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598606/how-to-use-scrapy-to-crawl-multiple-pages) example, but with the difference that I want to follow more that one link from the same page:

```
A
----> B.1
--------> B.1.1
----> B.2 
--------> B.2.2
```

To sum up, I want to save different types of data in the same item from root page A, B.1, B.1.1, B.2 and B.2.2. 
Can someone give me a toy example?

EDIt:

Image the following code:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    start_urls = [www.pageA.com]

    def parse(self, response):
        myitem = Item()

        # some initial data
        item['a'] =  response.xpath(...).extract()

        # extract all B.i links
        url_Bi_list = response.xpath(...).extract()

        for url_Bi in url_Bi_list:
            yield Request(url_Bi,
                  ...
                  callback=parseBi,meta=dict(item=myitem))

    def parseBi(self, response):
        my_new_item = response.meta['item']


        # some second data
        item['bi'] =  response.xpath(...).extract()

        # extract B.i.i link
        url_Bii = response.xpath(...).extract()

        yield Request(url_Bii,
                  ...
                  callback=parseBii,meta=dict(item=my_new_item))

    def parseBii(self, response):
        final_item = response.meta['item']

        # extract more data from B.i.i link
        # some third inner data
        my_new_item['bii'] =  response.xpath(...).extract()

        yield final_item
```

So, will this code structure work? I'm not sure when to yield item or request...

Answer (score 4):

to query multiple pages use the example [you just pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598606/how-to-use-scrapy-to-crawl-multiple-pages) (to control callbacks), and use the [`meta` parameter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) to pass information between callbacks in a `dict` form, pass an item to each callback lo later return it at the last callback.

```
def parseA(self, response):
    ...
    myitem = MyItem()
    # populate the item
    ...
    yield Request(url=<B url>,
                  ...
                  callback=parseB, meta=dict(item=myitem))

def parseB(self, response):
    my_new_item = response.meta['item']
    ...
    yield Request(url=<C url>,
                  ...
                  callback=parseC, meta=dict(item=my_new_item))

def parseC(self, response):
    final_item = response.meta['item']
    ...
    yield final_item
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand. When the parseB is called the <C url> could be an unknown.

Comment: share code if you want me to understand your case. about a method knowing or not knowing a URL to parse, how does that affect the item?

Comment: Ok, I just wrote an example of a code I was trying. But the results weren't good. The final item dictionary results is a bunch of mixed data

Comment: please check that I am passing a `meta` parameter. I don't see that on your code.

Comment: I don't know, have you tried it? also please correct the names of the items you are populating inside every callback.

Comment: Ok, it is working better, i.e. the data is not all mixed, but every entry in repeated twice. It might be because the first parse will yield twice.

Comment: Great, so now you know how to share the same item on multiple callbacks right? Please accept the answer and upvote if you think the answer helped you.

Comment: No, but I already knew that (I just forgot to put them here). My issue is with the full structure. Like this is giving multiple equal data values. And I think is because to the multiple yields on the first parsing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110683/discussion-between-elrull-and-miguel).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I seen that seems to do the job is [scrapy-inline-request](https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-inline-requests)