# WikiRank parser

Tags: javascript, python, html, parsing

Need help with data extraction from http://wikirank.net.

This service has API, but it is limited only to quality and popularity score. I need particular metrics (length, references, sections and so on) of selected Wikipedia articles, which are used in calculating these scores. From [relevant study](http://www.mdpi.com/2227-9709/4/4/43) I find this formula:

```
\frac{1}{c}\sum_{i=1}^cnm_{i}
```

Where "nm" is normalized metric "i".

Maybe there is a way to extract these particular metrics from HTML/Javascript code of the web version of the service.

Are there any Python libraries for solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the solution in Python, following code can be useful:

```
import urllib2, re
metrics_names=['Len.','Ref.','Img.','Sec.','RL']
resp = urllib2.urlopen('http://wikirank.net/en/Chelyabinsk')
page = resp.read()
m=re.findall('<metrics>([^<]+)<',page)
metrics_values=m[0].split(',')
metrics={}
for num in range(len(metrics_names)):
    metrics[metrics_names[num]]=metrics_values[num]
```

In this example *metrics* will have following values:

```
{'Img.': '100', 'RL': '52.46', 'Sec.': '100', 'Len.': '77.12', 'Ref.': '40.71'}
```

Answer (score 0):

in python libraries like `scrapy` and `BeautifulSoup` a can be used

( https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/10/beginner-guide-web-scraping-beautiful-soup-python/ )

the distribution on http://wikirank.net/  looks like a *stable distribution* ( *power law* in log-log plot ) cf the graphics on  http://math.bu.edu/people/mveillet/html/alphastablepub.html

( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution )

you can also scrape multiple pages with scrapy :

- [How to use scrapy to crawl multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598606/how-to-use-scrapy-to-crawl-multiple-pages)
- https://abuhijleh.net/2011/02/13/guide-scrape-multi-pages-content-with-scrapy/
- http://mherman.org/blog/2012/11/08/recursively-scraping-web-pages-with-scrapy/

Comment: Thanks, but what about data from separate pages, which describe particular article? For example http://wikirank.net/en/Berlin